# Generating terraform script from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is there a way in which we can generate terraform script for the accessible resources available in a given region for aws?

Comment: No, generally not.

Comment: I see some answers recommending Terraformer, but in my experience it wasn't very useful. I personally thing it is much better to write your Terraform templates and run `terraform import` of the resources.

Answer (score 2):

To generate a complete setup of terraform based on an existing AWS account, you can use e.g. this tool
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer

Answer (score 0):

We've been working on this project and thought it might be useful for some of you. Check out https://www.kapstan.io/generate-terraform . It's a tool we built to convert AWS infrastructure into Terraform code using Google Terraformer. Would appreciate it if you could give it a spin and share any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: it would be nice to show a usage example suited for this question post.

Comment: The tool mentioned above does exactly that. Without any installation, you can extract all your existing resources in a terraform code version. You can review & update the terraform as needed before applying it elsewhere. 
There is a demo video available on the page - you can generate terraform in 3 simple steps.